# Substring html tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sub string and remove the `,` which appears within the span tag and display the name alone. Below are the two cases which needs to work.

```
Case1: <span class="datatableheader">No results found, </span>
Case2: <span class="datatableheader">Jude Gomes, </span>
```

A single function should help in removing the `,` in both cases and display the result as

```
<span class="datatableheader">No results found </span>
<span class="datatableheader">Jude Gomes </span>
```

Appreciate for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself @Kolink. Very irritating when people do not show their appreciation for the effort others put in! Especially those who manage to find the time to answer as many questions as they can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".datatableheader").html ($(".datatableheader").html().replace(",",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not widely recognized that [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) accepts a callback function:

```
$('.datatableheader').html(function(i,old) {
    return old.replace(/, ?/g, '');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fBY4/1/

Comment: +1, if the selector `'.datatableheader'` evaluates to more than one element this comes handy.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
 var parts = id.split(':'); //because u have case1: or case2: 
// it will split into string in array//

$('#parts[1]').replace(",",""));
//try to print that it will work
```

nice question.